# static_cast with an explicit rvalue conversion operator

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I am writing a simple wrapper class, and I want to provide explicit conversion operators to the wrapped type. The following code compiles fine with `gcc`

```
class wrap
{
    double value;
public:
    explicit wrap(double x) : value(x) {}
    explicit operator double&&() && { return std::move(value); }
};

int main() {
    wrap w(5);
    double && x (std::move(w) ); //ok
    double && y = static_cast<double&&>(std::move(w)); //clang reports an error here
}
```

But `clang` reports an `error: cannot cast from lvalue of type 'typename std::remove_reference<wrap &>::type' (aka 'wrap') to rvalue reference type 'double &&'; types are not compatible`.

As far as I know (see the latest draft, **5.2.9 §4**) `static_cast<T>(e)` has the same semantic has `T t(e)`, but clang does not refuse the latter.

Which compiler is right?

Comment: Looks like a clang bug. The error doesn't even make any sense. There's no way `std::move` could return an lvalue.

Comment: Known bug, tracked here: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19917

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clang bug [19917](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19917). From the section of the standard you mentioned, §5.2.9/4:

> An expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)`
>   if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`.

In this case, `T t(e);` is well-formed and compiles on both compilers, so `static_cast<T>(e)` should too. GCC correctly accepts it.